# Maximal time for an object vertically swinging on a rope to complete a full circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems, string

> An object mass $1 \, \rm kg$ hangs on a rope length $1 \, \rm m$. The object gets pushed with minimal horizontal velocity required to swing a full vertical circle, i.e.: keeping the rope stretched.
>
> What time $t_c$ does it take to complete that intact circle?

I added conclusion near end.

I have seen similar questions and answers to describe minimal horizontal velocity and variable velocity along the circular swing path, and to compute maximal tension on the rope. They all use conservation of kinetic + potential energy and balance centrifugal force with gravitational force at the top of the circular swing path.

But I have not seen the time described.

I ask because I wonder how that time compares to time $t_v$ when just pushing the object straight upward with minimal vertical velocity required to reach same top height $2 \, \rm m$ and to come down again.

Because in the first case the minimal velocity is bigger than in the second case, but, in the second case the distance is smaller than in the first case.

So would $t_c$ be bigger or smaller or equal to $t_v$ ?

I found (classical exercise: using distance formula for falling object (no rope attached) in time)

$t_v \simeq 1.3 \, \rm s$

and

$t_c \simeq 1.2 \, \rm s$

but I am not sure I am reasoning correctly.

On the other hand, times near $1 \, \rm s$ feel realistic to me for both.

As requested: here is my original approach which I was not sure to be correct.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from math import pi, sqrt

# define velocity in function of height
# see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/motion-in-a-vertical-circle/
>>> def v(h):
...     return sqrt(9.81*(5-2*h))
... 

# test some values
>>> v(0)
7.003570517957251
>>> v(1)
5.424942396007538
>>> v(2)
3.132091952673165

# f(h) is the (non elliptic) integral of v(h) (Wolfram)
>>> def f(h):
...     return -1.04403*(5-2*h)**(3/2)
... 

# find average velocity
>>> (f(2)-f(0))/2
5.314290126372764

# find time
>>> (2*pi)/5.314290126372764
1.182318834268865
```

Later, having seen expert answers I replaced height by angle.

code:

```
# import some stuff

>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.integrate import quad
>>> from math import pi, sin, sqrt

# velocity function v
# note h = 1 - sin(x) and v^2 = g * (5 - 2 * h)

>>> def v(x):
...     return sqrt((9.81)*(3-2*sin(x)))
... 

# test some values

>>> v(-pi/2)
7.003570517957251
>>> v(0)
5.424942396007538
>>> v(pi/2)
3.132091952673165

# values look as expected

# integrate velocity from -pi/2 to +pi/2

>>> res, err = quad(v, -pi/2, pi/2)
>>> print(res)
16.507274579464244


# find average meters per second

>>> res/pi
5.254428692593845

# find time for distance 2pi

>>> print((2*pi)/(res/pi))
1.1957884814453341
```

Note that in both cases $t_c \simeq 1.2$

I am also not sure how precise numerical integration really is.

So I asked question in this exchange to compare outcome.

**conclusion**: mistake in my approach is to calculate **average** velocity to find time. One must **integrate inverse** of **angle** velocity to find time.

Both given answers are correct. They give $t_c \simeq 1.289 s$ and so $t_c$ is a little bit bigger than $t_v \simeq 1.277 s$.

Comment: Thanks for adding homework-and-exercises tag. I am new here and not really sure if it is biased rather positive or negative, but, overall, I am happy to get some as opposed to none reaction.

Comment: How did you calculate the time $t_c$?  Did you integrate the velocity around the circle?

Comment: @BowlOfRed like gandalf61 I integrated the velocity around the circle, but, not the angular velocity, rather the length of the tangent velocity vector. Perhaps that's a wrong approach.

Comment: The time to push the bob and _almost_ reach the top dead center and come down again can be almost infinite depending on how close the vertical the rope goes.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou : for $t_v$ I was not thinking about having a rope attached. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Funny side effect: if one launches object from *top* (not bottom) with (in $m/s$) half a circle per second i.e.: $v_t = \pi$ then it will turn around intact circle because it just so happens : minimal $v_t \simeq 3.13 \lt \pi$ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

the energy is:

$$E=\frac 12\,L^2\,m\,\dot\phi^2-m\,g\,L\,\cos(\phi)$$

and the rope tension T :

$$T=-m\,(\dot\phi^2\,L+g\,\cos(\phi))$$

at t=0

$$E_0=\frac 12\,L^2\,m\,\dot\phi^2(0)-m\,g\,L\,\cos(0)$$

the rope tension at $~\phi=\pi~$ must be greater then zero

$$T(\phi=\pi)\ge 0=-m\,(\dot\phi^2(\pi)\,L+g\,\cos(\pi))\quad \Rightarrow\\
\dot\phi^2(\pi)=\frac gL\quad,
\dot\phi^2(0)=-\frac gL$$

from here solving $~E=E_0~$ for $~\dot\phi~$ you obtain

$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac gL}\sqrt{3-2\,\cos(\phi)}\quad\Rightarrow\\
\int_0^{2\,\pi} \left(\sqrt{\frac gL}\sqrt{3-2\,\cos(\phi)}\right)^{-1}\,d\phi=\int_0^{t_f}\,dt$$

this is Elliptic Intergral , you obtain
$~t_f~\approx 1.29\,[s]$

the start velocity $~v_0=L\,\dot\phi(0)=-L\,\sqrt{g/L}~$

Comment: Do you have a few more digits or is it exactly $1.28$? I ask because for $t_v$ I find   $1.277101713628202$. So which one ($t_v$ or $t_c$) would be larger?

Comment: Having $L=1$ isn't $\sqrt{g} \simeq 3.13$ the velocity for $\phi = \pi$ at the top?

Comment: I can write you more digits , but this will never be 1.277 ? . The velocity at the top is correct . By the way you didn’t wrote your approach to solve this problem?

Comment: OK so $t_c$ is not equal to $t_v$. Do you happen to know which one is larger? About my approach. I commented I integrated sqrt(9.81*(5-2*h)) to find mean velocity but, I am not sure if that is a good method. After seen expert answers I replaced h with sin(x). The time is almost equal around 1.2 (not 1.3). I will add original approach to my answer as well.

Comment: One remark: I tried to program the integral but near $0$ the expression $2cos(x)-3$ is negative so we enter the domain of complex numbers when taking square root. Is that OK?

Comment: Probably it should be  $ ~3-2\cos(\varphi)~$ from 0 to $2\pi$

Comment: right: and the time is $1.289 s$

Comment: I have ticked your answer as solution. Still I wonder is your $t_c$ closer to $1.28$ or (like what I calculate with your and @gandalf61 amd my (inverse) integral) closer to $1.29$. In case closer to $1.29$  feel free to update answer.

Comment: the solution is $~4.037811638\,\sqrt{\frac lg}~$ and g=9.81....

Comment: thanks for confirming

Answer (score 3):

Let $\omega(\theta)$ be the angular velocity of the object when the taut rope makes an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal (taking angles below the horizontal to be positive). By conservation of energy we have

$\displaystyle \frac 1 2 m r^2 \omega(\theta)^2 = \frac 1 2 m r^2 \omega(0)^2 + mg r\sin(\theta)
\\ \displaystyle  \Rightarrow \omega(\theta)^2 = \omega(0)^2 + \frac {2g} r \sin(\theta)$

To keep the rope taut the tension in the rope must be greater than or equal to zero throughout the circle. In particular, at the top of the circle we must have

$\displaystyle T = mr \omega\left(-\frac \pi 2 \right)^2 - mg \ge 0
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \omega\left(-\frac \pi 2 \right)^2 \ge \frac g r
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \omega(0)^2 \ge \frac {3g} r$

To maximise the time taken to complete a circle we must minimise $\omega(\theta)$ and so we must minimise $\omega(0)$. So for maximum time we have

$\displaystyle \omega(0)^2 =  \frac {3g} r$

and so

$\displaystyle  \omega(\theta)^2 = \frac g r (3+2 \sin(\theta) )
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \omega(\theta) = \sqrt {\frac g r (3+2 \sin(\theta) )}$

Now that you have an expression for $\omega(\theta)$ you can in principle find the time to complete half a circle, which is

$\displaystyle \int _{-\frac \pi 2} ^{\frac \pi 2} \frac 1 {\omega(\theta)} d \theta$

and then you just double this to find the time to complete a full circle. In practice, I think finding an exact expression for the integral may be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So, am I right to calculate required minimum velocity at lowest point is around $5.4$ meters per second? I ask because elsewhere I found around $7$ meters per second. Sorry to miss the ball.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName The minimum velocity at the lowest point, when $\theta = \frac \pi 2$, is $\sqrt {5gr}$. If $r$ is 1 metre then $\sqrt {5gr}$ is about 7 m/s.

Comment: Right, I got your angle 90 degrees wrong. If $v$ is velocity at height $h$ (taking $h=0$ at lowest point), $v$ is indeed 7 and 5 halfway and 3 on top (approximately). And  $v^2 = 5g-2h$. I then integrated $v$ in function of $h$ from $0$ to $2$ to help find mean value to use to calculate time. But I am not sure if this method is valid or if my calculations are right. So I wondered if anyone has exact value for the time.

Comment: sorry it is : $v^2 = g(5 - 2h)$ which I found on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/motion-in-a-vertical-circle/

Comment: I calculated integral and it gives same result as @Eli. So now, can I tick *both* of you to have provided solution?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName Eli has gone further than I did and actually evaluated the integral, so they should have the tick.